# Python: PyQtGraph is not showing animation

Tags: python, graph, pyqtgraph

I have a graph with several nodes. Once the user clicks any of the nodes, the graph should hyperbolize in such a way that the clicked node should come at the center of the graph (usually the position of 2D coordinate system origin). When I click there is no update in the graph, however the new coordinate values of the node (scatter points) gets updated in file saved locally. Below is the function which would be used for rendering and update as well.

```
# Function to render the H2 tree map embedded in Poincare disc
def render_h2_tree(positions):

    global adj
    global nodeText
    # Configuring the PyQt graphic window
    pg.setConfigOption('background', 'k')
    pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'w')
    pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

    w = pg.GraphicsWindow()                 # creating an instance of the PyQt GraphicsWindow
    w.setWindowTitle('H2 tree for Emails')  # set the title of the graphic window
    v = w.addViewBox()                      # add a view box to the graphic window
    v.setAspectLocked()
    g = Graph()                             # create an instance of the class Graph
    v.addItem(g)                            # add the created graph instance to the view box

    g.setData(pos=positions, adj=adj, size=0.01, pxMode=False, text=nodeText)  # set the node in the graphic window

    # Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
    import sys

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to resolve the issue. After modification  the code looks like:

```
w = pg.GraphicsWindow()                 # creating an instance of the PyQt GraphicsWindow
v = w.addViewBox()                      # add a view box to the graphic window
g = Graph()                             # create an instance of the class Graph

# Function to render the H2 tree map embedded in Poincare disc
def render_h2_tree(positions):

    global adj
    global nodeText
    global w
    global v
    global g

    # Configuring the PyQt graphic window
    pg.setConfigOption('background', 'k')
    pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'w')
    pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

    w.setWindowTitle('H2 tree for Emails')  # set the title of the graphic window        
    v.setAspectLocked()        
    v.addItem(g)                            # add the created graph instance to the view box

    g.setData(pos=positions, adj=adj, size=0.01, pxMode=False, text=nodeText)  # set the node in the graphic window

    # Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
    import sys

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

After declaring the graphic window, the view box and the graph as a global item, I made it sure not to create any new instances for the same. This way when any node in the window was clicked the instance of all these items remained the same, and then the nodes could be plotted to their new 2D positions.